# WPF: "Cyclic reference found while evaluating the Style property on element 'ComboBox'" when changing ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, listbox

I have been debugging this case like crazy for the past day and I am yet to find a way to fix it without majorly changing the implementation of a custom control. So here is some back story:

I have a ComboBox and I am changing its Template in order to add a **ListBox** control in its drop down. For this purpose I have added a the ListBox control to the ComboBox's ControlTemplate after which I have bound the ComboBox and ListBox control's **SelectedItem** and **SelectedIndex** via a **Twoway binding** sometime like this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

All works perfect. But since I want to support themes of this control via changing the merged ResourceDictionary I hit this nasty issue that for the life of me I cannot get to the bottom of. If I execute a logic that clears the MergedDictionaries and adds new once in the **SelectionChanged** event of this ComboBox the "**Cyclic reference found while evaluating the Style of a ComboBox**" is thrown.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: are you using this merged dictionary in your Window or UserControl xaml file or a resource dicitionary file ?

Comment: The Styles for this custom ComboBox control come from merged ResourceDictionary in the App.xaml. When changing those dictionaries I do the following:
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( ... );

Comment: From my understanding , What are you doing is right. just i m worried about dioing that in App.xaml. What about using ResourceDicionary file ? and use it's uri when calling Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( ... );

Comment: Ohh I totally missed that from your comment, I am indeed using ResourceDicionary file and merging them via their uri.